# Invalid Format pki.privateKeyFrom... PKCS#8 with node-forge javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

From what I saw in Forge or node-forge in npm . It is not possible with Forge to generate a key pair from a passphrase for encryption with `RSA_OAEP`.
So I used to complement another library to generate a key pair from a passphrase, `Virgil-Crypto`

```
var passphrase = "password";
var salt = forge.random.getBytesSync(256);
var key = forge.pkcs5.pbkdf2(password, salt, 40, 16);
var keyPair = VirgilCrypto.generateKeyPair(keyPBKDF2.key,VirgilCrypto.KeysTypesEnum.RSA_2048);
// keyPair.publicKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- [...] -----END PUBLIC KEY----- "
// keyPair.privateKey = "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----- [...] -----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----- "

var publicKey = forge.pki.publicKeyFromPem(keyPair.publicKey); //passed

var privateKey = forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem(keyPair.privateKey); //fail
// Uncaught Error: Could not convert private key from PEM; PEM header type is not "PRIVATE KEY" or "RSA PRIVATE KEY".
```

`"-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----` is `PKCS#8` format after searching in google but i don't found a function for read my privateKey.

How i can import him to Forge `rsa` privateKey ? or it's possible to generate key pair from a passphrase for encryption with `RSA-OAEP` ?

Thank you and sorry for my english.
regards

Answer (score 1):

You have an encrypted private key here.  You'll need to decrypt the key and convert it into a node-forge key before you can use it.

Something like this would probably work:

```
// decrypts a PEM-formatted, encrypted private key
var privateKey = pki.decryptRsaPrivateKey(keyPair.privateKey, 'password');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the `keyPBKDF2.key` parameter to the `VirgilCrypto.generateKeyPair` function, which uses it as a passphrase to encrypt the private key. If you don't want the key to be encrypted, pass a single argument for the type:

```
var keyPair = VirgilCrypto.generateKeyPair(VirgilCrypto.KeysTypesEnum.RSA_2048);
```